# page loaded by js function cant load another page using js function js html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

take this [sample as reference](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/gvmRX/) it is a menu bar at top of page when the menu bar is hover it has drop down menu in the dropdown menu when i click on the menu it will load the same menu on the left and the content in the middle of the page the left menu is sort of a marker that there are other pages to see...it is the same as the submenu in the menu page..my question is why is the submenu on the left not clickable i tried alert on the button click of the submenu but it wont show my code goes like this

this is the index.php

```
<body >
<div id="header">
    <?php include ('pages/menupages.php'); ?>
</div>  
<div id="body">
    <div id="bodycontainer" >
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
                <td>
                    <div class="leftsidecolumn" id="leftcolumncontainer">

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="middletd" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <div class="middlecolumn" id="middlecolumncontainer">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <div id="footer">
        <?php include ('pages/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

top menu menu

```
<div id="headermenu">
                    <ul >
                        <li id=""><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li id=""><a href="#">product</a>
                            <ul class="">
                                <li><a href="#">computer and other devices</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="desktop"><a href="#">desktop</a></li>
                                        <li id="laptop"><a href="#">laptop</a></li>
                                        <li id="phones"><a href="#">mobile phones</a></li>
                                        <li id="consoles"><a href="#">consoles</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu3</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu6</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu7</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu8</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>           
                        <li id=""><a href="#">menu3</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">submenu.2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
```

computer list

```
<div id="sidemenucomputer" >
        <div id="" class="leftnavigation headerimage">
        <img src="images/computer.png"/>    
            <ul class="leftnavigationlist">
                                        <li id="leftdesktop"><a href="#">desktop</a></li>
                                        <li id="leftlaptop"><a href="#">laptop</a></li>
                                        <li id="leftphones"><a href="#">mobile phones</a></li>
                                        <li id="leftconsoles"><a href="#">consoles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

thi is the js

```
$('#desktop').click(function() {
                    $('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/desktopcontent.php');
                    $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/computerlist.php');
                });



$('#leftdesktop').click(function() {
                    alert("desktop");
                });
```

when i click desktop it will load the menu list on the left side and content in the middle content.now in the left list the menu are not clicked because the alert is not showing is this not possible or i am doing it wrong

Comment: Your example does not match your code examples. Please show us the actual code, or update the fiddle example with the jQuery lines.

Comment: ok sir wait i work on it for a bit

Comment: please look at update..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> change your code:

```
$(document).on('click','#leftdesktop',function() {
    alert("desktop");
});
```

Comment: perfect but i have one question you see i have multple menu if i use it like this how can i do other menu...do i need to make `$(document).on` for every menu?thank you for fast response

Comment: like this $(document).off('click.leftnavigationlist').on('click.leftnavigationlist','.leftnavigationlist li>a',function() {alert("desktop");});